# Print a docstring of a program to stdout in Julia

Tags: julia, docstring

Julia accepts `?sin` on the command line to display a help text. I believe such help texts are implemented as docstrings. I would like to print such docstrings from my Julia program at runtime. How to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
julia> @doc sin
  sin(x)

  Compute sine of x, where x is in radians.

  sin(A::AbstractMatrix)

  Compute the matrix sine of a square matrix A.

  If A is symmetric or Hermitian, its eigendecomposition (eigen) is used to compute the
  sine. Otherwise, the sine is determined by calling exp.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> sin(fill(1.0, (2,2)))
  2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
   0.454649  0.454649
   0.454649  0.454649
```

Comment: You can also just use the `@doc` macro directly (e.g. `@doc sin`).

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know `@doc` returned the md string.

Comment: I wrote a simple function to test the current ideas. In VS Code, `@doc sin` gives the markdown output formatted as it should with colors and everything. Executing the same program in the Linux shell gives no output from `@doc sin`. Is it possible to get formatted output in the shell?

Comment: VSCode (probably) calls `display` automatically on the return value. In a non-interactive environment you have to call `display`/`show` on the result yourself.

Comment: I guess you forgot to print it. `julia -e "print(@doc sin)"` . Or if you want the colors and format, `julia -e "display(@doc sin)"`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot guys! @JunTian: If you add your `display` trick to the answer, I will accept it  as the best answer.